# How to automatically squeeze a title?

Tags: sectioning, pdftex

After some comments, I am going to revise the question, so that it is more understandable.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\section*{This is a very long title, that goes over several lines and I would like to have the characters squeezed, so that it fits in one single line}
\end{document}
```

This section title will go over several lines, since I use *twocolumn* for the document. I have two columns and thus less than *half* the witdth of an a4paper for the section title. Of course, this example is *extreme* and I do not have **such** long titles in my document. Mine do overflow the line by one word only or so.

Now, I am looking for code, that does *automatically* measure the length of the section title and then will *adjust* it (squeeze it!), so that the whole title finally fit's in one line.

Does anyone know how to do that?
The *characters* shall be squeezed, as in *condensed fonts*, **not** the *whitespaces* reduced whithin the text.

I hope someone has a solution and thanks for all effort!
Also, I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Giving a proper answer that works for you requires knowing which classes and packages you are using. In other words, you should provide a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-minxampl.html) so we can help you

Comment: A generally useful pointer for this kind of needs is the `titlesec` package but if you are using special classes such as memoir or the KOMA classes then you have other specific options

Comment: Welcome! As mentioned, we need an MWE. Right now, I just find your question confusing anyway. Neither of the sample titles will exceed a line, so there is no need to squeeze them. (Unless your text block is 2mm wide or something.) Moreover, doing this automatically and in general seems to be a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: This question may be relevant, if I understand your question properly: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/different-vertical-spacing-parskip-between-concurrent-section-titles-and-parag

Comment: Hello everyone

I use

**\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}**

Because of the twocolumn, titles such as

**\section*{*This is a very very very long title and don't like it going over two lines*}**

Are oftentimes broken to over several lines.
What I would like is, to have the characters squeezed, so that they fit in one line.
I would like to have that automatically done.
My guideline is: Shorten the title, if it's not readable anymore. But before, I'd liked it squeezed.
And thank you everyone! This is really a great helping platform!

Comment: A minimal working example is needed. (Bordaigorl and cfr already mentioned this)

Comment: I edited the question. See the picture above for an example how it should look like.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: *Why* are you trying to do this? Why risk making a section header well-nigh unreadable?

Comment: Those aren't section titles and why are you so reluctant to provide an MWE which might actually enable somebody to provide effective help? I tend to assume you can't really be that interested in a solution. (That may be wrong, but it seems a reasonable working hypothesis.)

Comment: @Olöf: Are you after doing [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FETCT.png)? ...an extreme example, of course. If so, will you only use `\section*`, or perhaps non-starred `\section` as well?

Comment: @Werner Yes! That is what I was looking for. I only use \section*. Does that make a difference, if I would use it starred or non-starred? The example text is really exaggerated. Normally my titles are so short that only *one* word would go into the next line and that is really not nice :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some conditions that seem to be met:

1. You only use `\section*`.
2. You typically have section titles that are shorter than the column width, but occasionally roll over to two lines.
3. Roll-overs should *always* fit on a single line.

(1) helps because it simplifies the measurement (there is no sectional number in the title). We can use [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to redefine `\section` an manage the `*` gathering if you don't want to change your code.

For (3) we can use [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}` to resize content to fit within the `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \sbox\z@{\normalfont\Large\bfseries #3}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@>\linewidth
    \oldsection*{\resizebox{\linewidth}{\ht\z@}{\usebox\z@}}
  \else
    \oldsection*{#3}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{A short title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\section*{This is a very long title, that goes over several lines and I would like to have the characters squeezed, so that it fits in one single line}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\section*{This is a very long title spanning two lines}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section*{XyzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\end{document}
```

We store the `\section` title in a box and compare the `w`i`d`th of that box against `\linewidth`. If it is wider, we shrink it horizontally to `\linewidth`, otherwise we just set the title as-is.

Comment: Isn't `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox\z@}` easier?

Comment: @egreg: That'll scale the height proportionally and for long-word-wrap-arounds might make the text seem squished vertically as well. But sure, it's an option.

Comment: @Werner Thank you! The solution works very well, just, what I was looking for.
But another question: Could that may be extended towards:
a) `\subsection*`
b) `\subsubsection*`
c) Titles of colorboxes where I use the following code:

E.g.



`\begin{document}    % \usepackage{tcolorbox}
                                % \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}


\newtcolorbox{ABox}[1]{colback=DarkGreen!45!white,
colframe=LightSlateBlue!75!black,
breakable,
title={#1}}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a following solution:

```
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}               
\newcommand\squeeze[1]{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{#1}\lsstyle}
```

I can call it e.g. by:

```
\section*{\squeeze{-75} *This is a very long title that is now being squeezed into one line*}
```

Nevertheless, I have to say "squeeze"! and by what amount ("-75") every time.

Does someone know a way, that a text is **automatically** squeezed into exactly **one** line?

Thank you everybody!

Olöf

Answer (score 0):

The first comment has to be that shrinking titles beyond LaTeX's defaults is likely to be difficult to read or look out of place and so it's probably a better choice to rename the section.

Having said that, it might be preferable to have a `\sectionshort[Short Title]{Full Title}` command which prints `<Short Title>` if `<Full Title>` can't fit on the line.  We could even prefer squeezing the full title before resorting to the short title.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19414 gives a nice explanation of how space between words are managed, to achieve the squeezing I've just reduced the normal spacing between words - there may well be alternative and preferable routes to do it.

```
\newlength{\reducedsectionspacing}
\setlength{\reducedsectionspacing}{0.333pt} %This changes the natural spacing between words
\newlength{\defaultsectionspacing}
\setlength{\defaultsectionspacing}{\fontdimen2\font}
\newlength{\sectiontitlelength}

\newcommand{\shortsection}[2][]{
\section{\setlength{\sectiontitlelength}{\widthof{\thesection\quad}+\widthof{#2}}\ifdim\sectiontitlelength<\linewidth#2
\else
\fontdimen2\font=\reducedsectionspacing
\setlength{\sectiontitlelength}{\widthof{\thesection\quad}+\widthof{#2}}\ifdim\sectiontitlelength<\linewidth#2
\else\fontdimen2\font=\defaultsectionspacing
\ifx\\#1\\#2\else#1
\fi\fi\fi
}}
```

First we test whether the given title is longer than the space available in the line, then we reduce LaTeX's default word spacing to `\reducedsectionspacing` and see if that's enough to put it on a single line.  If that's not good enough we then put the short title if it's there otherwise the full title.

Using the following to test

```
\shortsection[This title is short]{This title is far far far far too long to be practical}
\shortsection[This title is short]{This title is far far far too long to be practical thus it gets ignored and replaced by the short version}
\shortsection[This title is short]{This isn't too long}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\shortsection{This title is far far far far too long to be practical}
\shortsection{This title is far far far too long to be practical thus it gets ignored and replaced by the short version}
\shortsection{This isn't too long}
```

We see that where feasible, titles have been squashed together, short titles substituted.

[image]

Comment: Dear Mr Bowen,
Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately, it solves a *substitution* problem and not the original *squeezing* problem. But in other cases it is an interesting opportunity, thank you!