# Avoid line break in title

Tags: line-breaking, titles

How do I stop the following title wrapping, so that it extends slightly into the margin instead? I don’t want to [change the font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100271) or [squeeze the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313069/how-to-automatically-squeeze-a-title).[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{\raggedright A rather long title that I would prefer on one line}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try without the `\raggedright` command?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used `\raggedright` in the MWE because proportional spacing doesn’t really make sense if I plan to ignore the right margin.

Comment: Reduce the verbosity level of title (e.g., "A rather long title.").  The smaller text under the title is just to explain its meaning, so this practice is almost always less painful than destroy the layout of the document.

Comment: @Fran Changing the title of a document to fit the formatting sounds unlikely to be good advice. And I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "the smaller text under the title".

Comment: @Roly I am referring, of course, to the content of the section `:)`. Often the titles of whatever are ridiculously and unnecessarily long, but a good title must be brief, no self-explanatory. As the content must explain the title, when is possible choose a  shorter version, most probably that will be is the best version. My advice is not to fit  the content to a desired format , but  the  universal  rule of thumb  of "The good, if brief, is twice as good".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the argument of `\section*` in an `\mbox`:

[image]

Speaking for myself, I don't think that suppressing a line break is a good idea here. In its stead, I'd recommend re-writing (i.e., shortening) the argument of `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\section*{\mbox{A rather long title that I would prefer on one line}}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both `\mbox` and `\rlap` seem to do the trick, but `\mbox` feels slightly more idiomatic, so I’ve accepted this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't advise this, but you can make TeX think that the heading has 0pt width and everything else sticks out to the right using `\rlap`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{\rlap{A rather long title that I would prefer on one line}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks nice and simple, thanks (and of course I recognise that this isn’t best pratice).

Comment: And it avoids an `overfull hbox` warning that you get with `\mbox`.

Comment: @Roly if you want to stick to more LaTeX-like syntax, instead of `\rlap{<your title>}` you could also use `\makebox[0pt][l]{<your title>}`, which would look the same and won't throw an overfull warning, too.

Comment: +1: And thanks for the help with the other question.

Answer (score 3):

If pdftex may be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\section*{\textls[-10]{A rather long title that I would prefer on one line}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Microtype's `\textls` sets letter-spacing correction. It has an optional argument. In our case, we use some negative value. In this case, contrary to two other solutions, our line is not too long.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you say something about what `\textls` actually does?

Comment: @Roly Is te extended answer enough for you?

Comment: Ah. That looks useful, but I don’t think it answers the question, which explicitly ruled out changing the letter spacing.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like letter spacing also doesn’t work with XeTeX at the moment.

Comment: @Roly Only changing the font size or squizzing the text was prohibited. :-)